# Excel VBA: Using Evaluate Match function with range as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

My variable `found_match` will return "A7:A45" when I use debug.print, this range can change depending on other factors, but currently it returns this.

I have a Match function set up which currently works if I type in "A7:A45" as it's range, but if I replace it with the variable it doesn't work.

```
row_num3 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A7:A45=""" & condition_1 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!B7:B45=""" & condition_2 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!F7:F45=""" & condition_3 & """),0)")

Debug.Print row_num3
```

The above works, but if I replace the range with the variable it returns an error when I use debug.print:

```
row_num3 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'found_match=""" & condition_1 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'found_match2=""" & condition_2 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'found_match3=""" & condition_3 & """),0)")

Debug.Print row_num3
```

This code is running on ws3 (worksheet 3), but it's looking for it's match on ws1 (worksheet)

How can I format the Match function to work with variables as the range rather than specifically typing the range (eg. A7:A45)

Thanks!

Comment: If `found_match` is a variable, not a named range, you need to concatenate it in: `"MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'" & found_match & "="""`

Comment: `row_num3 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & found_match & "=condition_1"")*('" & ws1.Name & found_match2 & "=condition_2"")*('" & ws1.Name & found_match3 & "=condition_3"")` I think I have still formatted this incorrectly EDIT: found_match is a variable. I find the concatenation super confusing

Comment: What is `found_match`?  Is it a range variable or string variable storing a string address?

Comment: `found_match = "A" & row_num2 & ":A" & lastrow3` (row_num2 and lastrow3 return a number) EDIT: I haven't set a Dim for it

Comment: `& ws1.Name & "'!" & found_match`

Comment: @ScottCraner do you mind putting it in context of the entire match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
row_num3 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & WS1.Name & "'!" & found_match & "=""" & condition_1 & """)*('" & WS1.Name & "'!" & found_match2 & "=""" & condition_2 & """)*('" & WS1.Name & "'!" & found_match3 & "=""" & condition_3 & """),0)")

Debug.Print row_num3
```

Comment: I have noticed that this returns the number of rows after the earliest range, for example: if found_match is row 19, and lets say the next row with the match is row 21, row_num3 will return 1. I think this is because it's counting from the row AFTER 19 and then returns the number you have to add to get to the next match which in this example is 21. The only way I've been able to make this work is to do (these variables names are not great, I'll change them at some point) `row_num4 (new variable) = row_num2 + row_num3 + 1`. And this returns 21, but it don't know if this is the best way?

Comment: @Sam .. I appreciate you trying to explain here. But I am not able to understand your problem, I think what you should do is ask the question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) clearly explaining what you are trying to do with the help of Screenshots and Examples. I am sure someone will suggest you the best way of achieving it.